# jQuery infinite carousel bug (duplicate entry created)

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I've tryed to create a infinite carousel, and the problem is that some slide duplicate with no reason, and if I try to make a click event on the second thumbnail to activate rotate, it's work for the first x(total of original) slides (this code has been cut out due too the problem, maybe if someone could point me the right way to do it)

I have no choice regarding the HTML structure, so I need to work with it without changing it, so I hope is not a structure problem, you can see the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/PDbQR/ or running at http://webserver.lewebsimple.ca/~tempcode/

Thank you for your help !